# deleting a linked list of linked lists in android

Tags: java, android, linked-list, garbage-collection

I'm writing an android app with some linked lists of small linked lists of objects (maybe 3 dozens of 1000 objects each).

I want to choose a policy for memory management since I often have to delete and rebuild them (since data are interdependent, it is easier than modifying state.)

I don't know if I can rely on DDMS tools, which only works in debug mode, for so small lists.

When deleting one of them, I want to know if it is common practice to just clearing it (hoping GC will clear the sub lists) or if I have to visit the whole structure myself.

In other words, should I

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<MyObject>> theList = getTheList();

void free(){
    theList.clear();
}
```

or

```
void free(){
    LinkedList<MyObject> subList;
    for(subList:theList) subList.clear();
    theList.clear();
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once theList elements are not referenced, they will be automatically cleaned by the garbage collector. Your first proposal is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't c++. In java it is common, GC will delete these objects if you do not have any others references to them and will not using them in future. I would stay with simple clear.

In other way, if you want to speed up your program, by using less `new` operator when recreating this structure, I would suggest to use object-pool and reuse created objects.